# reloading log from file with links in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing

I have a TextPane which contains logs. Basically a collection of texts and Links. Links are provided using Jlabel. Now the User can also store the log.
Till this point, it is working correct. 
Later a user can reload the file, but now how do I make those links workable. Before, I had inserted JLabel and worked. But now how do I detect a link (it can match with the text)?

How do eclipse and netbeans deal with such situations?

Comment: It is going to be difficult to answer this question from your description alone. Can you formulate an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use JLabels. Set propr content type (text/html) and use links.

See for example this http://java-sl.com/tip_autocreate_links.html to see how links automatically created.

Comment: I cant using Html because contents are added dynamically at the go. Each time, I then will have to reframe tags etc

Comment: Add marker attributes or use custom tags http://java-sl.com/custom_tag_html_kit.html or even write own Writer like described here http://java-sl.com/editor_kit_tutorial_reader_writer.html